# How to get unique values in one column based on unique values in other column

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

How can I transform this

A   P   1
A   Q   2
A   P   1
B   P   1
B   Q   2
B   R   3
C   P   1
C   P   1
C   Q   2

Into this:

A   P   1
A   Q   2
B   P   1
B   Q   2
B   R   3
C   P   1
C   Q   2

More info:
The values in 1st column have common values in Column B which have a relative values in Column C. Column B has multiple of common values for Column A. I want to filter/use other tools to only show unique values in Column B along with Column C which will unique to same value of Column A.

There are also other columns which are different values per entry but I don't care about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simple `UNIQUE`:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:C)
```

[image: 0]